# Adding leading zeros to extracted month from date on SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I'm currently have this code working without issues:

`cast(func.extract('month', cast(metric.table.c[date_field], Date)), String(2))`

What I want to achieve is to have leading zeros on months that are composed of single digits.

I tried:
.zfill(2) it gave me an error:
zfill cannot be applied to CASE or Comparable object.

I tryed if len() then  '0'+
I got:
Boolean value of this clause is not defined

Which would be the correct way to fill with zeroes that string?

Thanks!
Edit, some more context, DB is DuckDB (Postgres)

```
        elif agg == DATE_AGG.MONTHLY.value:
        select_field = (cast(func.extract('year', cast(metric.table.c[date_field], Date)), String(5))
                        + ' '
                        + cast(func.extract('month', cast(metric.table.c[date_field], Date)), String(3))
                        ).label("datefield")

        order_field = [func.extract('year', cast(metric.table.c[date_field], Date)),
                       func.extract('month', cast(metric.table.c[date_field], Date))]
        return dict(select_val=select_field, order_by=order_field)
```

Comment: Please provide a minimum reproducible example

Comment: You might find it easier to retrieve the month values as integers and then *format them* with leading zeroes in the place(s) where you need leading zeroes.

Comment: I'm constructing a query here and will use this field to request that data. It's dynamic so I am trying to format this here to make the next (query) code reusable. Will update with the context around this line to make the code more understandable. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In raw SQL (PostgreSQL dialect), you would use [LPAD](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING) to accomplish this. The signature is `LPAD(text, length, padding_char)`, so `LPAD('1', 2, '0')` -> `'01'`.  A complete `extract` example might look like this:

```sql
test# select 
          lpad(
            cast(
              extract(
                'month' from cast('2023-01-01' as date)
              ) as varchar
            ), 2, '0'
          ) as month;
 month 
═══════
 01
(1 row)
```

A working SQLAlchemy equivalent looks like this:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import cast, func

tbl = sa.Table('t77404367', sa.MetaData(), sa.Column('date', sa.String))

engine = sa.create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2:///test', echo=True)
tbl.drop(engine, checkfirst=True)
tbl.create(engine)

with engine.begin() as conn:
    vals = [{'date': d} for d in ['2023-01-01', '2023-11-01']]
    conn.execute(tbl.insert(), vals)

with engine.connect() as conn:
    stmt = sa.select(
        func.lpad(
            cast(sa.extract('month', cast(tbl.c.date, sa.Date)), sa.String),
            2,
            '0',
        ).label('month')
    )
    for row in conn.execute(stmt):
        print(f'{row.month=}')
```

Comment: it was func.lpad, thank you!